# Can eq(index) in JQuery accept an index more than 9?

Tags: jquery

Does `eq(index)` in JQuery can accept index more than `9`?

And if yes, there is any work around? or alternatives?

I am asking because i wrote some code using JQuery for scrapping.

And when testing on this page:

http://www.zappos.com/n/p/p/7498055/c/181710.html

with this JQuery selector "HTML BODY CENTER TABLE TBODY TR TD TABLE TBODY TR TD TABLE TBODY TR TD TABLE TBODY TR TD TABLE TBODY TR TD TABLE TBODY TR TD FONT:eq(11)"

it fails, and i found it just work if the index less than 10, and any number greater than 9 it get the wrong elements.

Comment: I know its too long, do you have an idea to make it shorter?

Comment: if so I would try and put an id on one of those tables (if they have not already got them) then select from that

Comment: as i said in my question, its a scrapping function so those websites sure not mine

Comment: ok sorry, you could go direct to the table e.g $('table:eq(5) tbody tr td font:eq(11)')

Comment: ok, fine, please put your comment as an answer and tell that the problem was in the path its self, so i can accept the answer and share with others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it accepts any index as long as it is in-range.

If you're asking for an alternative to **limit** it to an index of 9, then you could limit it by using some code like this:

```
if (index <= 9 && index >= 0) $('p').eq(index).foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

see example of use of index with eq() to set focus on input fields

http://jqueryminute.com/blog/set-focus-to-the-next-input-field-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to screen scraping Zappos, we do have a public API you could use instead to grab the product information.  Check out http://developer.zappos.com for more information